# Вывод текста на страницу

Tags: javascript, html

Во время вызова функции результат выводится на новой странице (адрес тот же, но страница пустая, и на ней только результат).
Что делать? Как правильно выводить текст?

```
function someFunc() {
    var min = document.getElementById("min").value;
    var max = document.getElementById("max").value; 
    var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
    rand = Math.round(rand);
    document.write(rand);
}
```

Результат должен выводиться между тегами

```
<span id="rnd-num"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/write), вызов `document.write()` в уже загруженном документе автоматически вызовет `document.open()`.
Вывод: `document.write` стоит использовать только там, где это действительно необходимо, и с пониманием принципа его работы.

Вывод результата в `#rnd-nam` с использованием выбора элемента по ID и заменой его текстового содержимого (`textContent`):

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var minElement = document.getElementById("min");
var maxElement = document.getElementById("max");
var result = document.getElementById("rnd-num");

function someFunc() {
    var min = minElement.value;
    var max = maxElement.value; 
    var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
    rand = Math.round(rand);
    result.textContent = rand;
};

button.addEventListener("click", someFunc);
```

```html
<input id="min" value="1" /><br/>
<input id="max" value="100" /><br/>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Generate" /><br/>
<span id="rnd-num"></span>
```

Comment: Мне нужно каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку, заново выводить рандомное число и только не в конец страницы а там где я прописую document.write(). Или как Text Node можно вывести среди нужных тегов в середине html документа?

Comment: @RomanKravets поменял код. Есть небольшие косметические изменения, но суть та же.

Comment: Заработало, спасибо.